# AWS amplify push analytics doesn't update aws-exports.js. Error: No credentials, applicationId or region

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm facing an issue with AWS Amplify and Analytics in my React application. When I configure and run my app.js as shown below, I get an error

> Error: No credentials, applicationId or region

Here's the relevant code snippet from `app.js`:

```
import { Amplify, Analytics } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

Analytics.autoTrack('session', {
  enable: true,
  provider: 'AWSPinpoint'
});

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Analytics.record({ name: 'app launched' });
  }, []);
}
```

I noticed that `aws-exports.js` does not automatically populate fields like `aws_mobile_analytics_app_id` and `aws_mobile_analytics_app_region`.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!